# Replace TextBox.Value Excel with recordset Fields.Value from Access

Tags: excel, vba

let say i have 3 "SerialNoCubicle" number as a trigger; "8", "17", "18".

When the combobox.value is filled with one of those, then the rest of textbox.value will replaced from access database. The problem is, i could only do it for the first, which is if the value was "8" then textboxes.value is replaced. But if "17" or "18" the textbox.value still empty.

I could do it manually by changing

```
If txtSerialNoCubicle.Value = 8 or txtSerialNoCubicle.Value = 17 or _
txtSerialNoCubicle.Value = 18 then
```

but if the user input another value beside "8", "17", "18" for "SerialNoCubicle" then the code wont work for new value

```
Private Sub serialnocubicleDB()
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, r As Long
Dim sql1 As String

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ace.OLEDB.12.0; " & _
"Data Source=E:\Database.accdb"
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

sql1 = "Select * FROM tblspecification "

    rs.Open sql1, cn
    If txtSerialNoCubicle.Value = rs.Fields("SerialNoCubicle").Value Then
        TextBox1.Value = rs.Fields("Project").Value
        TextBox2.Value = rs.Fields("ProjectNo").Value
        TextBox3.Value = rs.Fields("No&DateofDrw").Value
        TextBox4.Value = rs.Fields("DrawingNumber").Value
        TextBox5.Value = rs.Fields("NameofCubicle").Value
        TextBox6.Value = rs.Fields("SingleLineLayout").Value
        TextBox7.Value = rs.Fields("PlantofTest").Value
        TextBox9.Value = rs.Fields("TypeofProduct").Value
        TextBox10.Value = rs.Fields("IPofProduct").Value
        TextBox11.Value = rs.Fields("Substation").Value
    End If
    rs.Close
    cn.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of querying the whole table, just get the record you want

```
Private Sub serialnocubicleDB()
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, r As Long
    Dim sql1 As String

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ace.OLEDB.12.0; " & _
    "Data Source=E:\Database.accdb"
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    'Query for the specific serial number
    '  should be probably using parameters here depending on your use case
    sql1 = "Select * FROM tblspecification t where " & _
           " t.SerialNoCubicle=" & txtSerialNoCubicle.Value

    rs.Open sql1, cn

    If Not rs.EOF Then
        TextBox1.Value = rs.Fields("Project").Value
        TextBox2.Value = rs.Fields("ProjectNo").Value
        TextBox3.Value = rs.Fields("No&DateofDrw").Value
        TextBox4.Value = rs.Fields("DrawingNumber").Value
        TextBox5.Value = rs.Fields("NameofCubicle").Value
        TextBox6.Value = rs.Fields("SingleLineLayout").Value
        TextBox7.Value = rs.Fields("PlantofTest").Value
        TextBox9.Value = rs.Fields("TypeofProduct").Value
        TextBox10.Value = rs.Fields("IPofProduct").Value
        TextBox11.Value = rs.Fields("Substation").Value
    Else
        TextBox1.Value = ""
        TextBox2.Value = ""
        TextBox3.Value = ""
        TextBox4.Value = ""
        TextBox5.Value = ""
        TextBox6.Value = ""
        TextBox7.Value = ""
        TextBox9.Value = ""
        TextBox10.Value = ""
        TextBox11.Value = ""
    End If

    rs.Close
    cn.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: theres an error in defining line for sql1, then i changed to "Select * FROM tblspecification where 'SerialNoCubicle= & txtSerialNoCubicle.Value'" it works, but only for txtserialnocubicle.value = 8. the rest of it doesnt work...

Comment: "doesn't work" means what *exactly*?  That's not telling us much which might help us help you...